# Remove border outline when key stroked with javscript or css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone point me in the right direction for my problem. I wrote a rule that will out line my input box when there is no value submitted. But now would like to remove the red outline when I start typing in the input box. Suggestions?

[image]

CSS

```
  .placeholder-red-text {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

JS

```
return x.classList.add('placeholder-red-text');
```

HTML

```
<input id="red-border-error"></input>
```

Comment: You mentioned `I wrote a rule that will outline my input box when there is no value submitted`. Share your code of HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use another attribute of your input to set the style, i can think of three simple examples:

1:  Make the input **required** and check if the input is **valid**

```css
.foo { outline: 2px }
.foo:valid { outline: 0 }
```

and in your html

```html
<input class="foo" required>
```

2: Do the same with a **data attribute** and some js
like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fa3Lkd07/1/)

```js
const fooEl = document.querySelector('.foo')

fooEl.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  fooEl.setAttribute('data-foo', e.target.value)
})
```

```css
.foo {
  outline: 2px yellow solid;
}

.foo:not([data-foo=""]) {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="foo" data-foo="">
```

3: Same as before but setting a new class, or just setting a boolean value for the data-attribute instead of the value..